# How to match a numbers in different language?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a numbers which is in japanese text and a number in english text.

```
example:
In japanese language six=６
In english language six=6
```

So when I compare this value it return false
I have used CompareTo() but it doesn't returns 0

How to match this values????

Comment: Is that japanese? I don't think so. http://www.omniglot.com/language/numbers/japanese.htm

Comment: You can try `var comparer = StringComparer.Create(new CultureInfo("ja-JP"), true);`
`bool areEqual = comparer.Equals("6", "６");`

Comment: @GAPS areEqual = false

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I got six from japanese language page.

Comment: They're not the same, they might represent the same number but they're 2 different characters so I don't think you are going to get C# to say that they are. Have you considered using a lookup table?

Comment: @Ashigore I know they are different character. So I want to know is there any way so get that they are same

Comment: In my job I've had to use Japanese a lot, and I never struggled to find a 6 when the language setting was japanese, do they parse the same? you are saying that they are text..

Comment: @Proneet This is unicode char called [_Fulwidth digit six_](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff16/index.htm) It has nothing to do with japanese chars

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC)` to reduce international digits into their english/arabic equivalents.

```
"６".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC); // returns "6"
"6".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC); // also returns "6"
```

You can extract the comparison into a method:

```
static bool IsEqualAfterNormalizingKC(string s1, string s2) {
    if (s1 == null && s2 == null) return true;
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null) return false;
    return s1.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC) == s2.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC);
}
IsEqualAfterNormalizingKC("６", "6"); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the strings into integers (`int`) using one of the common parsing methods for .NET. Then, compare the two integers.

Data comparison/interpretation should be performed on the native representation which in this case is an `int`.

Comment: I poped open linq-pad when I saw this question and tried this but completely failed - if you get this to work I'd be interested to see the code

Comment: @AaronAnodide                  "６".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC); // returns "6"
"6".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC); // also returns "6"        its working